# GridBagLayout Issues

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtextarea, gridbaglayout

I can't get `GridBagLayout` to work.

Here is a picture of a result I want(top left) and the result I am getting(center)

[image]

I want to have a text field followed by an add and remove button on the same row, and then have multiple rows like it shows in the top left.

I dont have a lot of experience with `GridBagLayout` and it is starting to get pretty frustrating. This is only a small portion of my GUI. `GridBagLayout` is the layout I want to use. How can I get the 3 component chunks to align on the Y-Axis and not keep adding to the X-Axis?

```
    file1_tf = new JTextField(20);
    file1_tf.setEditable(false);
    file_select_panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    file_select_panel.add(file1_tf);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    file_select_panel.add(add_f1_button);
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    file_select_panel.add(rem_f1_button);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    file_select_panel.add(file3_tf);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    file_select_panel.add(add_f3_button);
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    file_select_panel.add(rem_f3_button);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve, but based on you code, the simplest would be to ensure you are passing the `GridBagConstraints` along with the component you are adding when you add them...

```
file_select_panel.add(file1_tf, gbc);
//...
file_select_panel.add(add_f1_button, gbc);
//...
file_select_panel.add(rem_f1_button, gbc);
//...etc...
```

You might find taking a closer look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) helps, in particular, take a look at the section labelled *"Specifying Constraints"*

Comment: Just WOW. That's embarrassing.

Comment: Welcome to my world ;)